# downloading with web request

Tags: c#, webrequest, download

I want to get a link from a `TextBox` and download a file from link.
But before downloading file, I want to know the size of the file in advance and create an empty file with that size. but I can't.
and another question, I want to show percentage of download progress. How can I know data is downloaded and I should update the percentage?

```
         WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL); 

         WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();     


         totalSize  = request.ContentLength;//always is -1

        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            f.SetLength(totalSize);
        }


    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new  

    System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadFile (URL, savePath);
```

Comment: I've update the answer. The previous one was maybe a little cryptic.

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to use the WebClient with its DownloadFile Function, which has an async callback for events like Completed or ProgressChanged.

Getting the size of the file in advance would be a step harder though.

Comment: You can get the file size by reading the http headers from the response.

Comment: That would be an idea, yes :)